# Check in a Django template if all parameters are available for URL-generation (#NoReverseMatch)

Tags: django, django-templates

## Description

I have a HTML template that is used by several views. It's all the same but one HTML link is different. So I thought about checking in the template what's the request.path and change the link accordingly.

## Problem

Because not all parameters for all possible URLs (IF is not true) are passed to the template by all views I get an NoReverseMatch.

#### This was my idea for the template:

```
{% url "first" as first_url %}
{% if first_url in request.path %}
<button type="button" onclick="$.get("{% url 'foo' a b c %}");">Foo</button>
{% endif %}

{% url "second" as second_url %}
{% if second_url in request.path %}
<button type="button" onclick="$.get("{% url 'bar' a %}");">Bar</button>
{% endif %}
```

## Question

Is there a way to use Django's `{% url %}` though not all parameters are available? Or do I really need to extend the template?

Comment: You create your proper custom tag...

Comment: @NathanIngram What custom tag do you mean?

Comment: Django Custom tag... {% url %} is django tag, now you can implement your own

Comment: Just for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags